# Highcharts/Highmaps Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using a Hicharts US map to display the number of companies we have in each state with a drilldown option which then shows companies by county within a state.
Data is in JSON format and comes from a CRM API call. Below is a sample:

```
[
  {
    "drilldown": "al",
    "code": "us-al",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "drilldown": "wy",
    "code": "us-wy",
    "value": 1
  }
]
```

Everything has been running fine for 2 years. Yesterday we moved servers and **without a single change to the script** I am now getting **'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined error**'.

I have my code available here: https://jsfiddle.net/7u5m3ht6/5/

Please, note that in the fiddle I am including JS code inline but in my original script it runs from a file called main.js and it's included at the bottom of the page with the rest of the libraries as such:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"</script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/js/companyTable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Highmaps` code you can not use the `map.js` module, because it is `Highmaps` itself but as a plugin for Highcharts or Highstock.

All you need to do is just remove this script:

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/43Lcbndu/

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I have been wracking my brain for two days trying to figure this out. I am wondering why it worked for two years with the map.js. and when I moved servers it stopped.

Comment: Just did. Thanks again.